# No resume after Hibernate or Standby

Tags: 10.10, kernel, hibernate, suspend-resume

When i try to reactivate my notebook after it went to standby or suspend mode the screen stays black. The only solution i have is to reboot the notebook by pressing the shutdown button. Anyone has any idea to fix the problem?

Comment: We would need a lot more info before giving any useful answer. Please list your notebook's make, model, specific configuration (specifications) and any proprietary drivers used.

Comment: Hangs of this nature can have a number of causes which appear similarly.  Is the backlight on for the screen (is it lit up in the dark)?  Are you able to switch virtual terminals to VT-1 (press ctrl-alt-F1), if this works you will see a black screen with a textual login prompt.  Does the machine respond on the network (ping <machinename>.local from another system)?

Comment: I also have this problem with the screen going black after suspend or resume on an Asus Eee PC 1201N.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 10.10, upgraded from 10.04 using the update manager.  Suspend and hibernate worked previously on Ubuntu 10.04.

The 1201N laptop seems to suspend and hibernate successfully and when I press the power button to return from suspend or hibernate is seems to work correctly (disk drive activity), however the screen simply does not display.

If I drop down to a terminal window (Alt-F1), still nothing is displayed.  If I do a Ctrl-Alt-Del keyboard combo then the laptop will reboot as normal and the display is resumed

Comment: I have tried to use the fix stated in the Ubuntu 10.10 release notes, but this has not worked

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MaverickMeerkat/ReleaseNotes

I also described this fix on my blog at:
http://jr0cket.blogspot.com/2010/10/ubuntu-1010-hibernate-suspend-bug-fix.html

Comment: Once I installed the nVidia closed source video drivers, the Asus Eee PC 1201N resumes correctly from hibernate.

There seems to be a power management related bug with the open source video drivers for nvidia cards.

Comment: How much swap have you allocated?

Comment: Are you able to switch to a different run-mode? (alt-control-f1). A Full kernel log would be preferrable, since there are literally hundreds of possible issues that can cause this.

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is no visible activity or information added to it for several months. I have flagged a moderator and am voting for it to be closed. If you feel that the question is not abandoned and that you still suffer from this issue please flag a moderator so that it can be re-opened.